# Mysql query result is not save file as csv format using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch data from mysql database and save it to as .csv format using php. But no luck. It's don't save the query output as .csv format. Is there any problem in my code or is there any solution to solve it.

Thanks for your help.

```
<?php
// Database Connection
$host="host..";
$uname="username..";
$pass="password...";
$database = "database...."; 

$sqlagentdetails = "select * from users WHERE company_name != ''";
$rowresult = mysql_query($sqlagentdetails); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowresult, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $pc1 = $row['pc1'];
    $pc2 = $row['pc2'];
    $pc3 = $row['pc3'];
    $pc4 = $row['pc4'];                      
    $emailAgent = $row['user_email'];                      
    $user_id = $row['id'];


$myQuery =  mysql_query("
 SELECT * 
   FROM user_property upr 
  WHERE (postcode = '$pc1' OR
         postcode = '$pc2' OR
         postcode = '$pc3' OR
         postcode = '$pc4') AND
         datediff(CURDATE(), upr.creation_date) <= 7 AND
         NOT EXISTS(SELECT ofr.property_id 
                      FROM offers ofr 
                     WHERE ofr.property_id = upr.property_id AND
                           ofr.agent_id IN(SELECT id 
                                             FROM users 
                                            WHERE company_name !=''
                                          )
                   )
ORDER BY property_id DESC");


if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
$headers = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
    $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);
}

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}

}// first while statement

?>
```

Comment: What is `$result->fetch-array()`? What is `$result` actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is `MYSQLI_NUM` doing here? And what is `$result`? try:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQuery)) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
 }
```

You should stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Check out [PDO](https://www.php.net/PDO) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli)

Comment: there was a typo, there was a `$` before mysql_fetch_assoc which is wrong

Comment: Oh..I just missed to db connection. Now it's showing the result like that..but don't output as .csv file. Please check the result to http://propertyjungle.com.au/export.php

Comment: I can't see what you're doing wrong, as there are some stuff that are not coming from the code you posted here... I see it is somewhat in a .csv format that needs a bit of fixing

Comment: Well.. Now it' getting only 1 row result. Can't get desire result.

Comment: It is your query then, the while will loop through all the results returned by the query